# Ruby calling hash values returns nil

Tags: ruby, hash, key-value

I have a code

```
def pitch_class(note)
    note_hash = {:C=>0, :D=>2, :E=>4, :F=>5, :G=>7, :A=>9, :B=>11} 
    note_hash[:note]
end
```

but whenever I try to call the value inside it returns nil.

```
pitch_class("C")
#=> nil
```

How can I call the values using the key as the argument?
Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

`"C" != :C`. Therefore, `pitch_class(:C)` will work.

You can also use `String#to_sym` to force the argument inside the function, if you want to be able to accept a string argument. Or you can create the hash with string keys in the first place.

EDIT: Also, `:note` is not `note`.

EDIT2: As a performance tweak, I'd rather have `note_hash` declared outside the method, rather than instantiating it each time the method is called. Stuffing it into a class constant (`NOTE_HASH`) would be the best way to handle it.

Answer (score 3):

You hardcoded `:note` symbol instead of reading parameter passed to your method:

```
def pitch_class(note)
    note_hash = {:C=>0, :D=>2, :E=>4, :F=>5, :G=>7, :A=>9, :B=>11} 
    note_hash[note.to_sym]
end
```